# Convert a Classic ASP project to another language so I can develop on Mac

Tags: macos, asp-classic, web.py, scripting-language

I have a site in ASP that I want to convert to a language that I can host on my Mac (I haven't found a practical way to host Classic ASP). The site connects to a MySQL database to pull data which is represented using Google Charts in a Dashboard.

I don't have experience with many other scripting languages, but am willing to learn. It seems that *Web.py* would be the easiest. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late answer but this caught my eye.  Last year I moved a very complex aplication from ASP.NET to run on unix using the Mono framework.

I found Mono and the MonoDevelop editor to be solid tools, and had no problems running my code natively on linux and osx.

Now you're talking about classic ASP.  Mono does have the opensource "xsp" and "xsp2" web servers built in... I believe xsp can handle classic ASP.

Using Mono bought us the 12 weeks I needed to go heads down and convert the entire application to Python using web.py.  I agree it's a great framework, especially if you want a lot of control and not be bound by a templating based system like Django.

Regarding Stare's comment... if you do virtualization I'd strongly recommend VirtualBox.  Parallels has burned all their bridges with me.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use a virtualization software on your mac to run an IIS (like VMware Fusion or Parallels). The you could easily develop ASP on your MAC.

Thats what I'm doing (Even .NET with Visual Studio) and it has been the best investment ever!